# How to save the attachments of a email in php?

Tags: php, email, imap

I am retrieving the emails and then parsing into the database.

But the problem is i am able to retrieve the email but the attachment part is also shown on the browser.I need to save this attachment part to the some location .The format of attachment is text/plain.

here is my code

```
<?php
    $inbox=imap_open("{xyz.com:995/pop3/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX", "username", "password");
    $count = imap_num_msg($inbox);

    for($i = 1; $i <= 1; $i++) {
     $raw_body = imap_body($inbox, $i);
     echo $raw_body;
     imap_delete($inbox, 1);
    }
    imap_expunge ($inbox);
?>
```

here i have retrievd a email

But i dont know how to save the attachment .
The attachment is also shown below the body of the email when i am using the `imap_body`.

So how should i separate these two..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by analysing the mail with [imap_fetchstructure()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetchstructure.php) you can get a list to the different parts of the mail. With a [imap_fetchstructure()](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.imap-fetchbody.php), you actually take the parts interesting to you. Have a look at the latter documentation for an example code in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Well now you know how to extract the attachments from the email source from Lars response.
I think you might also need to decode the attachment.
To do that you need to know how it was coded.
1. base64_encode()
2. chunk_split()

The code to encode a file looks like this:

```
<?php
$body .= "--".$boundary1 . $this->line;
$body .= "Content-Type: " . $file_type . "; name=\"" . $file_name . "\"" . $this->line;
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" . $this->line;
$body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $file_name . "\"; size=" . $file_size . ";" . $this->line;
$body .= $this->line; // empty line

$fp = fopen($file_url, 'r');
do {
  $data = fread($fp, 8192);
  if (strlen($data) == 0) break;
  $content .= $data;
}
while (true);

$body .= chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
$body .= $this->line;
$body .= $this->line;
?>
```

The result is something like this:

```
--ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
Content-Type: text/plain; name="sample.txt"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="sample.txt"; size=123;

AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==
```

Now to decode it you need to do the 2 things again in reverse.
1. take the encoded part and strip all lines so you have a single line string
2. decode it
.. and of course save file to disk :)